# Detecting and isolating lines on green tennis table board

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to detect lines on a table tennis board, but there is allot of "noise" detected off the board (sides) and on the board as well.

There is also the issue of getting rid of the brand/wording on the table.

Basically want detect the white lines on the green table.

I have been looking at some examples, but being new to OpenCV doesn't help :-)

[image: Table Tennis Board][image: Edges][image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("table.jpg")
imgS = cv2.resize(img, (960, 1024))
#
# # Convert to grayscale first beforeget edges of the image

kernel_size = 5
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size), 0)
# get edges of the image

edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, 75, 150)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 50, maxLineGap=100)


# print(lines)

# draw "lines"
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    # print(line[0])
    # Draw the line on original image (img) and set color to blue and thickness 2
    cv2.line(imgS, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255,0), 2)


cv2.imshow("Edges", edges)
cv2.imshow("img", imgS)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You missed uploading the images and just added the link.

Comment: Apologies, added.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian blur
- Canny edge detection
- Create mask to keep white line contours
- Perform morphological transformations with a vertical kernel to isolate vertical lines
- Perform morphological transformations with a horizontal kernel to isolate horizontal lines
- Detect lines with `cv2.HoughLinesP()`
- Iterate through mask and find contours
- Draw contours onto original image

---

Canny edge detection

[image]

Next we use a special vertical kernel using [`cv2.getStructuringElement()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to filter out horizontal lines and extract only the vertical lines

```
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,3))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(remove_horizontal, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=5)
```

[image]

We do the same thing with a horizontal kernel to extract only horizontal lines

```
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,1))
remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
dilate_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(remove_vertical, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)
```

[image]

We combine the two to get the resulting mask

[image]

Finally we find contours on the mask and draw it on the original image. Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, (960, 1024))
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 150, 255, 1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))

# Find Vertical Lines
# ------ 
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,3))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(remove_horizontal, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=5)

minLineLength = 10
maxLineGap = 150
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilate_vertical,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),3)
cv2.imwrite('vertical_mask.png', mask)
# ------ 

# Find Horizontal Lines
# ------ 
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,1))
remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
dilate_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(remove_vertical, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)

minLineLength = 10
maxLineGap = 300
horizontal_mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilate_horizontal,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),3)
        cv2.line(horizontal_mask,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),3)
cv2.imwrite('horizontal_mask.png', horizontal_mask)
# ------ 

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imwrite('remove_vertical.png', remove_vertical)
cv2.imwrite('remove_horizontal.png', remove_horizontal)
cv2.imwrite('dilate_horizontal.png', dilate_horizontal)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Notes: Other potential strategies and thoughts

- Use color thresholding and `cv2.inRange()` to isolate the white lines.
- To filter out the net, you can use a modified version of the above method but instead of using `cv2.HoughLinesP()`, use Numpy slicing to extract only the top/bottom halves and only search for lines using the top `1/4` and bottom `1/4` of image. Maybe something like this

```
top_half = remove_vertical[0:int(image.shape[0] * .25), 0:image.shape[1]]
bottom_half = remove_vertical[int(image.shape[0] * .75):image.shape[0], 0:image.shape[1]]
```

---

**Strategy to isolate only the middle line**

- Convert image to grayscale and Gaussian blur
- Canny edge detection
- Perform morphological transformations with a vertical kernel
- Dilate to enhance contour
- Find contours and filter using contour area

Canny edge detection

[image]

Next we use a special vertical kernel using [`cv2.getStructuringElement()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to filter out horizontal lines and extract only the vertical lines

```
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,9))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel)
```

[image]

Finally we dilate to enhance contours and filter using a minimum threshold area. Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, (960, 1024))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 120, 255, 1)

vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,9))
remove_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(remove_horizontal, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 50:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', image)
cv2.imwrite('canny.png', canny)
cv2.imwrite('remove_horizontal.png', remove_horizontal)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thanks for this @nathancy, I would also like to have the table boundary lines (around the edge of the table). The idea is to eventually detect in which "block" on the table the ball lands/bounces during a match.

Comment: Check the update. You can detect which block the ball lands on by checking if the ball is in the top or bottom half of the image using Numpy slicing

Comment: nathancy thanks allot for this, I can't wait to test it tonight. I suppose the same code should work using a webcam on the exact same table positioned in the centre above the table looking down at it?

Comment: It should, since it detects lines so the orientation shouldn't matter too much

Comment: thanks for the help so far, I ran your latest changes but found that the  contours of the vertical line in the top half of the image doesn't draw.

Comment: Is this for detecting all white lines? Is this for a new image?

Comment: I checked all the images you write to file and all seems fine just like in your screenshots above except drawing the contours on the original image. I have uploaded the new images produced

Comment: here are the new images, hope you can see them? [link](https://imgur.com/dqjHq49) [link](https://imgur.com/T2QVgX6) [link](https://imgur.com/TUYFfh6)

Comment: I just ran the code again using the original image and its detecting all the white lines just like in the result picture. Maybe old opencv version?? `pip install opencv-python --upgrade`